# How can I determine the size of words in bits (32 or 64) on the architecture?

Tags: go, cpu-architecture, 32bit-64bit

I am not looking for `runtime.GOARCH` as it gives the arch of the compiled program. I want to detect the OS architecture, say I run a 32-bit `go` program on a 64-bit machine, I need to identify it as 64 and not 32 bit.

Comment: You can look at the size of `int`. It is architecture-specific.

Comment: Since architectures are either 32 or 64 bit, you could map [goarchList](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/build/syslist.go) to either 32 or 64 bit. And use the value returned by `runtime.GOARCH` as key. [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/yOAHkLBpXuU).

Comment: Why do you want to know this? The only way it would matter would be to detect if your 32-bit program is running on a 64-bit architecture. Or if you want to create an installer/launcher for some other program. You already know the bitness of your program and 64-bit apps won't run on 32-bit machines.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Detecting the size of words is relevant when you perform a conversion from an `int` to an `int32`, for example. On a 64-bit arch, you'd potentially lose information.

Comment: Does the answer below answer your question? If yes, please accept it. If not, please specify what's missing.

Answer (score 4):

You can determine the size of `int`/`uint`/`uintptr` by defining an appropriate constant (called `BitsPerWord` below) thanks to some bit-shifting foo. As a Go constant, it's of course computed at compile time rather than at run time.

This trick is [used in the `math` package](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.1:src/math/const.go;l=40), but the constant in question (`intSize`) isn't exported.

```
package main

import "fmt"

const BitsPerWord = 32 << (^uint(0) >> 63)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(BitsPerWord)
}
```

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/59I0P9FoVfC))

### Explanation

1. `^uint(0)` is the `uint` value in which all bits are set.
2. Right-shifting the result of the first step by 63 places yields

- `0` on a 32-bit architecture, and
- `1` on a 64-bit architecture.

3. Left-shifting `32` by as many places as the result of the second step yields

- `32` on a 32-bit architecture, and
- `64` on a 64-bit architecture.

Comment: Interesting.  In C this wouldn't be valid; shifting an integer by more than the bit-width of the type isn't well-defined.  I assume Go does define the behaviour here, so `x >> n` on a 32-bit machine is required to zero an `x` of type `int`, for any `n` greater than or equal to 32?  Or is there something special about compile-time eval so this works but variable-count shifts can compile without extra checks?

Comment: Ok, apparently variable-count shifts in Go do have to compile with checks, when targetting x86-64, to preserve the Go semantics of shifting out all the bits for large counts: https://godbolt.org/z/sWfjcnWoW.  Actually also ARM64, since it only saturates the low 8 bits, not the whole thing.  So yeah, if your language defines that behaviour, take advantage of it.  You could instead maybe compare `^uint(0) == 0xFFFFFFFF` or something like that, which seems simpler and more "obvious" to me at least, but I don't know Go.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting! Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Hmm... is it really so? on a 32-bit architecture, the result of the first step yields 0, and no matter how you shift it, the result of the second step will always be 0, right?

Comment: Moreover, as per **The Go Programming Language**, the constant are compiled at the compile time, so that `const BitsPerWord` will be a fixed value, the same as `runtime.GOARCH` which gives the arch of the compiled program, and cannot be used to detect the OS architecture no matter which one it runs on.

Comment: @xpt In step #3, 32 is either shifted left by 0 (yielding 32) or by 1 (yielding 64). I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at in your second comment.

Comment: Compile & running you suggested code with 32 bit go on a 64 bit machine prints 32. Compile & running you suggested code with 64 bit go on the same machine prints 64. This code does not do what you think it does.

Comment: https://qvault.io/golang/constants-in-go-vs-javascript-and-when-to-use-them/ *constant are compiled at the compile time*

Comment: @Gerhard Were your comments addressed to xpt or me?

Comment: @Gerhard Sure, it's a bit more subtle than what I wrote in my answer. It depends on the architecture _and_ on the compiler used. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @jub0bs: No it depends only on the compiler. See https://go.dev/ref/spec#Constant_expressions - *Constant expressions may contain only constant operands and are evaluated at compile time.* The value is set at compile time.

Comment: online test: [32](https://godbolt.org/z/5aoP6bMqc) vs [64](https://godbolt.org/z/jPsr5odcb)

Comment: @Gerhard Thanks, that helps! That subtlety had escaped me. I'm not sure what the OP was after (architecture size or compiler's `int` size), or was aware of the subtlety in question, though. I'll fix my answer after some more research.