# Detect 32 or 64 bits machine (Understanding `32 << (^uint(0) >> 63)` )

Tags: go, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

It is said that the `32 << (^uint(0) >> 63)` expression can be used to detect whether the machine is 32 or 64 bits.

How so?

**UPDATE:**

The question was closed because of
[How can I determine the size of words in bits (32 or 64) on the architecture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69445434/)

however, that answer has two problems,

- on a 32-bit architecture, the result of the first step yields 0, and no matter how you shift it, the result of the second step will always be 0 (the given answer is wrong).
- Moreover, as per **The Go Programming Language**, the constant are compiled at the compile time, so that `const BitsPerWord` will be a fixed value, the same as `runtime.GOARCH` which gives the arch of the compiled program, and cannot be used to detect the OS architecture no matter which one it runs on.

**UPDATE:**

Found that the most reliable and portable way is to check with this under Linux:

```sh
$ getconf LONG_BIT
64
```

It won't depend on the language implementation of any programming language, and it can be used in shell scripts too.

Comment: The linked duplicate answer is bogus. Good luck changing anybody on stackoverflows mind.